# How to show UV islands in texture paint mode?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

So I have unwrapped my object but when going into texture paint mode the uv maps I unwrapped disappear. How do I fix this

[image]

[image]

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you want to see the edges of your UV islands as you paint in Texture Paint Mode? Since the UV islands are usually generated from marked seams, I looked in UI settings for a way to display marked seams while in Tex Paint. Unfortunately I do not see a setting for enabling this. Maybe it can be enabled through a Python command. At the very least, you can create a Color Grid texture and swap your paint texture with the col grid in your material when you want to verify where the seams are. Or paint the islands diff colors yourself, then paint the final over this.

Comment: You can choose the Image Editor instead of the UV Editor

Answer (score 0):

Using Moonbot's suggestion above - change to an Image Editor and if the UVs are still not showing, choose 'Display texture paint UVs' under 'View'.

Screenshot for illustration of the difference.
[image]

Comment: Chang to an image editor, do you mean the window itself?

Comment: Yes, if using a UV editor like on the bottom, the UVs are hidden outside of edit mode.